# Remove elements and reload page

Tags: jquery, checkbox, checked

I have a list of search results. The user selects the search results they wish to keep by ticking the checkbox. Once they have finished selecting they click "View Chosen Selection" and the page is reloaded with just their selection.

What is the best way of doing this? I am think jQuery remove() but I'm not sure how to reload the page.The page reload is a must because it will be made into a PDF.

```
<ul>
    <li class="property-list">
        <input type="checkbox" class="category1"></input>
        <div>content</div>
    </li>
    <li class="property-list">
        <input type="checkbox" class="category1"></input>
        <div>content</div>
    </li>
    <li class="property-list">
        <input type="checkbox" class="category1"></input>
        <div>content</div>
    </li>
    <li class="property-list">
        <input type="checkbox" class="category1"></input>
        <div>content</div>
    </li>
</ul>
<button>View Chosen Selection</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Reload page with location.reload(true) in javascript

Comment: Thank you - here is my code - it's not reloading   $( "button" ).click(function() {
 if (!$(".category1").is(":checked")) {
  $( ".property-list" ).remove(); }
  location.reload(true)
});

Comment: remove everything and put only location.reload(true) to see if it reloads. i think its not reloading because some bad function that is not executed.

Comment: yes you are right - works by itself. That means the remove part isn't working. ok

Comment: I think the remove isn't working because I need to use (this). Do you know how to write it properly - I think this is wrong if ($('input:checkbox')(this).is(':not(:checked)')) { //do something }

Comment: You dont need this. Check on w3schools how checked function works i forget how it works i think there is problem.

Comment: Ok it works now but when we reload it forgets what was selected and just refreshes the page

Answer (score 0):

I think description is a bit misleading, however have applied additional changes to align with the bug description. Ok, to achieve desired effect, please use the below code:

```
<ul>
    <li class="property-list">
        <input type="checkbox" class="category1" id="elem1"/>
        <div>content</div>
    </li>
    <li class="property-list">
        <input type="checkbox" class="category1"  id="elem2" />
        <div>content</div>
    </li>
    <li class="property-list">
        <input type="checkbox" class="category1"  id="elem3"/>
        <div>content</div>
    </li>
    <li class="property-list">
        <input type="checkbox" class="category1" id="elem4"/>
        <div>content</div>
    </li>
</ul>
<button>View Chosen Selection</button>
```

And the JS side (to keep the history of selected elements HTML5 Api sessionStorage has been used):

```
    $(function(){
        var sStorage = window.sessionStorage || {},    
           getVal = sStorage.getItem('elemId') || null,
           $button = $('button');

          // bind 'click' event with input DOM node
          $(document).on('click', 'input[type=checkbox]', function(e) {
          var $idAttr = $(e.target).attr('id');

          // eval if elem is checked
          var isElementChecked = 
                $('#' +$idAttr ).is(':checked') ? 
                  sStorage.setItem('elemId', $idAttr) :
                    sStorage.removeItem('elemId');
          });

          if (typeof getVal === "undefined" || getVal === '') {
              $('#'+ sStorage.getItem('elemId'))
          }            
          else {
              $('#'+ sStorage.getItem('elemId')).
                      attr('checked', true);
          }

          // bind 'click' evt with button
          $(document).on('click', $button, function(){
            return location.reload();
          });
    });
```

Comment: this just refreshes the page and doesn't keep what has been checked